# Not sure on Left Join, Outer Join, Unions or Minus?

Tags: mysql, join

Current work requires my to have a complex level of SQL syntax including these examples.

What in short is a left Join and where would you use it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The query you need depends on what you want to achieve. What do your database tables look like? What are you trying to do? What have you tried so far? What happened?

Comment: See example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

Comment: Downvoting question, because this information is available in literally every book and reference on SQL. @lazerk, you show no effort to answer this basic question for yourself.

Comment: Look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever you have written is a JOIN clause that is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

Including outer join or left join depends on the table structure and the requirement to pull data from those tables.

IF you are looking for what is left join ,

Left join returns everything from the left table and the matching records from the right table and if there is no match in right table the result is null for the right table

Let us know what are you looking for